# need to re-organize data frame by row to perform calculations on each row

Tags: r

My original data frame is this:
x

```
Team  Date   variable  value
A 2012-07-01 Score      13
A 2012-07-02 Score      12
A 2012-07-03 Score      2097
A 2012-07-04 Score      45
A 2012-07-05 Score      41
A 2012-07-06 Score      763
```

need to to be like this

```
z
    Team 2012-07-01 2012-07-02 2012-07-03 2012-07-04 2012-07-05 2012-07-06 
    A     13         12          2097      45        41         763

library(reshape)
z<-cast(x, Team + variable ~ Date)
```

I get a warning message stating this:

> Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Using `cast()` from "reshape" and `dcast()` from "reshape2" both give me the output you expect. Can you try again from a clean R session and see if you're still having the problem. If so, perhaps edit your question and add the result of `sessionInfo()`, which will tell us what version of R you are using and what packages (and their versions) are loaded.

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.2.1 reshape_0.8.4  plyr_1.7.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] stringr_0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dcast` from reshape2 package and it'll work!

```
x <- read.table(text='Team  Date   variable  value
A 2012-07-01 Score      13
A 2012-07-02 Score      12
A 2012-07-03 Score      2097
A 2012-07-04 Score      45
A 2012-07-05 Score      41
A 2012-07-06 Score      763', header=T)

library(reshape2)
dcast(x, Team + variable ~ Date)
 Team variable 2012-07-01 2012-07-02 2012-07-03 2012-07-04 2012-07-05 2012-07-06
1    A    Score         13         12       2097         45         41        763
```

### Edit:

You can use `reshape` function from stats. No additional package is required as above.

```
Y <- reshape(x, v.names='value', idvar='Team', timevar='Date',direction='wide')
names(Y) <- sub('value.', '', names(Y))
Y
  Team variable 2012-07-01 2012-07-02 2012-07-03 2012-07-04 2012-07-05 2012-07-06
1    A    Score         13         12       2097         45         41        763
```

Comment: I still get this error: Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length

Comment: That's odd, I worked well for me as you can see in the example above. Make sure you're using reshape2 and `dcast` as well.

Comment: @Jilber, +1 for base R `reshape()`. I was *just* about to post that alternative.

Comment: @Jilber, this kind of works but, the heading are as follows: value.2012-07-06. I need to revove the text "value." from the header. I used gsub("value.","", x), this ends up removing team and variable as well.

Comment: @user1471980 use `sub('value.', '', names(Y))` as in my edit which I already updated again.

Answer (score 0):

No special packages required:

```
xtabs(value ~ Team + Date, x)
#     Date
# Team 2012-07-01 2012-07-02 2012-07-03 2012-07-04 2012-07-05 2012-07-06
#    A         13         12       2097         45         41        763
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(value ~ Team + Date, x))
#   2012-07-01 2012-07-02 2012-07-03 2012-07-04 2012-07-05 2012-07-06
# A         13         12       2097         45         41        763
```

Comment: with this I get multiple rows with the same team. I need to have one team per row.

Comment: @user1471980, are you using the same data as in this question? I don't see any reason that you would get multiple rows per team with this solution.